# Remap right command key in windows

Tags: windows, remapping, wireless-keyboard, key-binding

I'm using a apple bluetooth KB on windows. How can I remap right command to become CTRL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2008/12/sharpkeys_30.html) will do it. [Tutorial here.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)